# Why does the following algorithm print random string of characters instead of an array?

Tags: java, algorithm

Here is my homework:

> Write a program which does the following: It returns an integer array arr2 of length n whose first k elements are the same as the first k elements of arr, and whose remaining elements consist of repeating blocks of the first k elements. You can assume array arr has at least k elements. The function should return null if either k or n is not positive.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
>        fill({1,2,3,5, 9, 12,2,
>         1},
>         3, 10) returns {1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1}.
>         fill({4, 2, 3,
>         12}, 1, 5) returns {4, 4, 4, 4, 4}.
>         fill({2, 6, 9, 0, 3},
>         0, 4) returns null.
> ```

Here is my code:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    int [] result = fill(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 12, 2, 1}, 3, 10);
    System.out.println(result);
}

    public static int[] fill(int[] arr, int k, int n){
        int[] arr2 = new int[n];
        int cnt = 0;
        if (k > 0 && n > 0)
        {
            while (cnt != n)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
                {
                    if (cnt != n)
                    {
                        arr2[cnt] = arr[j];
                        cnt++;
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            return null;

        return arr2;
    }
```

Comment: What you're doing wrong is not doing a bit of research before posting a question.

Comment: So changing to **System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));** is the only soln?

Comment: @Sputnik it's not the *only* solution; it's just the easiest.

Comment: You didn't show the supposedly "random string of characters", that almost certainly was not random.